# SSRS - copying report to a new folder increases speed 10x

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, database-administration

I've got a SQL 2008R2 report that runs 12,000 times a month. It averages 60-90 seconds per execution.

I've been using SQL for 12 years, but I just started this job 2-3 weeks ago, and am still trying to get my head around some of these SSRS performance problems. It goes without saying I've been re-indexing everything in order to help this report.

Here is a picture / dump of my execution log:

```
SELECT ReportPath, TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, TimeRendering, Source, [RowCount] 
FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog2
WHERE UserName = '_________' AND ReportAction = 'Render'
ORDER BY timeStart desc
```

http://accessadp.com/?attachment_id=562

```
ReportPath  TimeDataRetrieval   TimeProcessing  TimeRendering   Source  RowCount

/CubeReports/Freight Allocation 2954    4402    2039    Live    2348
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  39954   4087    2380    Live    2348
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  37718   3948    1888    Live    2348
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  39534   4317    1937    Live    2348
/CubeReports/Freight Allocation 3257    4206    2422    Live    2348
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation            37517 4164    2402    Live    2348
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  36127   4151    1986    Live    2348
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  36415   39888   2569    Live    19048
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  37544   41644   2071    Live    19048
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  37970   41003   2187    Live    19048
/RS Reports/Freight Allocation  38057   48085   1885    Live    19048
/CubeReports/Freight Allocation 3030    4558    2056    Live    2348
/CubeReports/Freight Allocation 3534    5232    2422    Live    2348
```

Please note, I do believe I know what the difference in 'RowCount' is. I had a subreport that was running a dataset (that wasn't important) and I removed it.

I thought that this was the reason for the increase in performance.. but I've double-checked and triple-checked that the subReports no longer have the other dataset (and this is refereced in the decrease in rowcount).  Unfortunately, that didn't translate into a decrease in processing time.

I downloaded the report from 'RS Reports', and deployed it to 'CubeReports'.. and I didn't change anything else on this version of the report.

I run it with the same parameters.. and now the copy of the report 'CubeReports' literally runs 10x faster.

I just can't figure out WHY this is happening? 
I REALLY need to find the solution and move it into production.

I've checked snapshots, history, execution caching.. none of that is turned on, it all looks like the default setting for both reports.. I've checked all the other options, and I just can't find anything that would explain this.

The only three options I see:

1. Report Builder 3.0 isn't 'compiling the report' as well as BIDs
   does.
2. Having 3-4 people running the primary report at the same
   time I'm doing the test is causing this problem. (We have 300
   employees, I really can't test anywhere else, because people run
   this all day every day).
3. Dropping the report and re-deploying the
   report, and crossing my fingers that this is going to make it run
   10x faster

Unfortunately, I've been able to duplicate the 10x speed increase consistently, I've ran it about 10 times each with the same parameters with the same result. Keep in mind, there is only 1 SSRS server, going against 1 database server. Same sprocs, same parameters.

10x worse performance in the production copy of this report.
10x better performance when I copy it to a new folder.

Primary ERP database is ~100gb, only 4 cores, only 16gb RAM. SSRS Server is on a VM, it is only 2 cores, only 8gb RAM.

There is one additional database that lives on the SSRS Server; it's actually a fairly large database- but not a TON of activity.  The other database (Bartender) is only 9gb data / 3gb log.

Comment: Is the data source embedded in the report? If not (a shared data source) is the data source identical between the two multiple versions? Particularly the credentials. Last week I ran into a difference because SQL authenticated connections have different defaults for some options versus Windows authenticated.

Comment: Is your dataset query embedded or do you use a sproc?

Comment: I use sprocs, the data soruce is identical.. the report is identical, I just copy it to another folder, and it runs 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that the report that runs faster says `Credentials used to run this report are not stored` and the report that runs slow says `Default report parameter values are missing`. I'm going to go back and double-check my defaults on the parameters.

I DO have a discrepancy in the default parameters. I'm probably going to go forward with dropping the report and re-deploying it.

Comment: note, dropping the report and re-deploying didn't fix the problem.

Comment: fixing the discrepency in default parameters didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I think this answers my comment to the original question. I'll find the option I tracked down a week or two ago and post an answer: I was having a similar performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with the two words folder name. Try in another folder with a space in it's name and check there.

Just my 2 cents... but i lived to see the holy "i" declared global.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar performance problem recently. Using SQL Server Profiler, I tracked it down to the exact same query executing. It would sometimes cause ~1000 times the reads as other queries. The differences appeared to be whether the query was called as SQL or through RPC.

Digging into this further, and by some trial and error, I found the key difference in my case was that the option for `ARITHABORT` was set differently for the different connections or users.

Unfortunately, I don't remember which setting was the fast one in my case. I wasn't getting a failed query, but the state of this option caused different execution plans to be used. Placing the statement `SET ARITHABORT ON` or `SET ARITHABORT OFF` at the beginning of my query brought everything into alignment. ARITHIGNORE and ANSI_WARNINGS are similar settings, so you might look at those as well.